# How to get temporary CPU Time

Tags: windows

In windows 7 Task Manager there is a colum CPU Time. It shows utilization of CPU for the process from the very begining of its execution. However I would like to get temporar CPU Time, e.g. from last 5 minutes. Some process is draining my battery and I wonder which one it is.

Comment: Within Windows7 task manager, under `Performance` tab you have a `Resource monitor` button : click on it and select `CPU` tab. From there you should be ready to go

Answer (score 0):

Within Windows7 task manager, under `Performance` tab you have a `Resource monitor` button : click on it and select `CPU` tab. From there you should be ready to go :

[image]

[image]